# gpx parser for PHP

Tags: php, gpx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GPX parsing patterns and “standards”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319556/gpx-parsing-patterns-and-standards)

Does anyone know of gpx parser for PHP ?

I am developing on server and need to upload gpx files from client(webpage and ios app), process them and save in database. I spent much time on internet, but I couldn't find it so far.

Our server needs to support gpx files, each of them can contain many tracks, and both tracks and points inside.

Comment: What have you tried? What hasn't worked? What research have you done to solve this problem? Have you tried searching the internet? What did you find? What was wrong with, say, the very top result in Google for `gpx parser for php`?

Comment: I searched in google, but only found library for ios and other one for parsing on client side !

Comment: Look at the [documentation for GPX](http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/). It's just a basic XML, so all you need is a basix XML parser and (maybe) some adapting.

Comment: We are currently using one basic XML parser. But we have trouble parsing in some edge cases. so we would like to apply some good parser specialized for GPX to do it instead !